# Why did Bilbo on Ravenhill prefer on the whole to defend the Elvenking?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit

Chapter XVII when the battle seemed lost and their faith doomed.

Why thus Bilbo preferred on the whole to defend the Elvenking?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**He likes elves better than Men, and Gandalf is his only friend on the field**

Asking why a fictional character "prefers" anything is basically asking for speculation.  But, on the whole, I think we can turn "idle speculation" into a pretty well-supported guess.

Firstly, Bilbo likes elves. A LOT.  We see it all over the Hobbit, and even in the Fellowship of the Ring.

Secondly, we know Bilbo does not seem to hold a particular grudge against the elven-king for imprisoning his companions in Mirkwood. From his reaction to Thorin & Company's handling of their meeting with the Elf King in Mirkwood and their reaction to Bard & the Elves request after Smaug was killed, we know he still views the Elves in a positive light, and thinks the whole thing is a huge misunderstanding.

So we've got that he has a positive view of elves in general since at least Rivendel.  We also know that he doesn't hold a grudge against these specific elves.  Which leaves us with Men of the Lake and the Dwarves.

The Dwarves of the Iron Hills are easy to dismiss.  Bilbo doesn't know those guys, why die with them?  His companions are estranged from him, and given the state of the battle when the line is said he would not have been able to reach them anyway.

The Men of Laketown are more of a mixed bag.  Sure they feasted the Thorin & Co. and helped out some.  But only some, and had been "besieging" the mountain for some time.  While Bilbo doesn't seem to hold this against them any more than he does the Elves of Mirkwood, he doesn't have the same pro-Men feelings as he does for elves.  To say nothing of what his cultural upbringing might have left him with prejudice-wise against "Big People."  (I wouldn't put much store in the last bit.  But seeing as how Shirefolk consider Breelanders "odd" it wouldn't surprise me if Bilbo ported that feeling onto all humans.  After all, Breelanders would likely have been the only humans he'd ever met, if he'd met any.  Also "Big People" seems to be the only term-that's-not-the-species-name Hobbits use.  Elves are elves. Dwarves are dwarves. But Men are sometimes "Big People" and that might mean something.)

Also Gandalf is with the Elvenking.  Biblo likes Gandalf, and beyond that knows Gandalf is after all a Wizard, so if any part of the Allied armies is coming through this it'll be the one with the wizard in it!

So when the book says "On the Whole" he'd rather die with the ElvenKing, that's probably summing it up neatly.  He doesn't have any special reason to die defending him, but of the available "Last stand positions" the Elvenking is the best option.

Comment: Everybody likes Gandalf

Comment: I guess just simply because of that and because it was at any rate the smartest option.

Comment: @SNR --- Except Denethor, Saruman, Sauron, ...

Comment: ...Wormtongue, the Mouth of Sauron, Durin's Bane,...

Comment: ...Bolg, Gorbag, Shagrat, The Great Goblin...